# seemingly simply javascript string building

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, string-concatenation

I thought this would really straightforward, instead I just lost a morning to it!

```
var insert = '<div class="main_content_half_panel_circle" id="circle_' + c + '"></div><script type="text/javascript">$("#circle_' + c + '").live("click", function(){ $(".main_content_half_panel_info_wrap").animate("left", ' + c_x + ', 400, "easeOutQuint") });</script>';
```

In firebug I keep getting 'unterminated string literal' - I've  tried a hundred variations, with different syntax, e.g. -

```
'$(".main_content_half_panel_info_wrap").animate({"left": ' + c_x + '}, 400, "easeOutQuint") });</script>'
```

...rebuilt the string from scratch, rebuilt it as a straight code block with no escaped characters and no variables included, then reinserted the ' + c + ' etc. Nothing. Have I gone code blind?

Any help VERY MUCH appreciated!

Page is at:

http://www.helicopterfir.com/dev

Scott

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have `</script>` inside a string in a script block, the browser thinks that the script block ends there. The script tag is simply parsed before the code inside it, so at that stage the browser doesn't know that it's inside a string.

Split the string up in the middle the closing tag:

```
...</scr' + 'ipt>...
```

Comment: @Guffa - unbelievable! Thanks you SO much - immediate success. You never see that stuff in the W3S docs! Really grateful after several hours of hair-tearing! Thanks again! Scott